# Why regular swap works with a pointer-to-pointer variable?

Tags: c, pointers, swap, function-definition, pointer-to-pointer

I know the difference between these two functions: `Swap(int *x, int *y)` vs `Swap(int **x, int **y)`.

But, I'm not sure how this kind of code works.
How is it possible to swap the address which the pointers point at with a regular `swap()` type?

For example, I believe that a local pointer-variable `a` is created and it points to `&ptr_x`, so when I do dereference `*x` it equals to `&x`.

So, `temp` (and also `*a` and `*b` which also function as integers) can hold the actual address of the `x`/`y` and that's why it works?

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
   int temp = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = temp;
}


int main()
{
   printf("in main:\n");

    int x = 2;
    int y = 8;

    int *ptr_x = &x;
    int *ptr_y = &y;

    printf("ptr_x points to = %p\n", ptr_x);
    printf("ptr_y points to = %p\n\n", ptr_y);

    swap(&ptr_x, &ptr_y);

    printf("ptr_x points to = %p\n", ptr_x);
    printf("ptr_y points to = %p\n", ptr_y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your compiler should be shouting warnings to you, because quite contrary to what you think the code *doesn't* work: It will give you *undefined behavior*. Listen to the compiler, and treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: Also, are you building for a 32-bit system? Where `sizeof(int)` just so happen to be equal to `sizeof(int *)`? Or if you're on a 64-bit system, doesn't the pointers use all 64 bits available to it, and the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) just so happens to be so that the bits of the pointers match that of a 32-bit `int`? Try using pointers created some other way, for example global variables or returned by `malloc`.

Answer (score 5):

The code is invalid. At least the compiler should issue a message that there are assignments (initializations) of pointers of different types without castings.

That is there is no implicit conversion between the pointer types `int *`, the type of the parameters, and `int **`, the type of argument expressions.

In general the function invokes undefined behavior because it is not necessary that an object of the type `int` is large enough to be able to store a pointer value.

It seems your program works either because `sizeof( int * )` is equal to `sizeof( int )`  or values of addresses are not large and can be stored in objects of the type `int`. Or there are swapped only low-significant parts of the pointers that are equal in size to `sizeof( int )` while most significant parts are the same for the both pointers.

To show that the code is invalid just use one pointer that points to a variable with automatic storage duration and other that points to a dynamically allocated memory.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
   int temp = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = temp;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int x;

    int *ptr_x = &x;
    int *ptr_y = malloc( sizeof( int ) );

    printf( "ptr_x = %p\n", ( void * )ptr_x );
    printf( "ptr_y = %p\n", ( void * )ptr_y );

    swap( ( int * )&ptr_x, ( int * )&ptr_y);

    printf( "ptr_x = %p\n", ( void * )ptr_x );
    printf( "ptr_y = %p\n", ( void * )ptr_y );

    // This can produce a run-time error 
    //free( ptr_x );  
}
```

The program output might look like for example

```
ptr_x = 0x7ffdcf002d98
ptr_y = 0x564608597eb0
ptr_x = 0x7ffd08597eb0
ptr_y = 0x5646cf002d98
```

As you can see there are swapped only less significant parts of the pointers that fit in object of the type `int`.

That is the expressions `*a` and `*b` within the function `swap` do not yield full values of pointers because they have the type `int`.

As a trick you could declare and define the function the following way:)

```
#include <stdint.h>

void swap(intptr_t *a, intptr_t *b)
{
   intptr_t temp = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = temp;
}

//...

swap( ( intptr_t * )&ptr_x, ( intptr_t * )&ptr_y);
```

Comment: The compiler is shouting, but it still works though. 
I'm using 64bit machine, so i believe it's the second option.
Can u give me an example for a case it won't work?

Comment: the address of x for example is 7ffd39c9cd64 which is 140725572980068 in decimal. 
It is more the the max value of int...

Comment: @MatanCode Try putting either `x` or `y` (but not both) at file scope and see what happens.

Comment: @MatanCode If the pointer to `x` is `7ffd39c9cd64` then I guess the upper 32 bits of the pointer to `y` is exactly the same as for the pointer to `x`? Then you're only swapping the low 32 bits of the pointers. Use pointers to integers created in different scopes, for example `x` being local and `y` allocated of the heap or being a global variable. Where the upper 32 bits are different.

Comment: @MatanCode See my appended answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks! this is more clear to me now.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow By the way, Why is dynamic allocation necessary?

Comment: @MatanCode Because in this case the more significant parts of the pointers are different as shown in the provided demonstration program.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  *Or there are swapped only low-significant parts of the pointers*  x86 **is** little-endian, so if the most significant 4 bytes of two 8-byte pointers are identical, this will "work".  But if you try this on a big-endian SPARC or ARM system it wouldn't "work".

Comment: @AndrewHenle I pointed to why his code can work. If to swap only most-signoificant parts then the code will not work.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

This swap function is excepting 2 pointers while you are passing addresses of pointer variables which has a type of int**. You will get undefined behavior because of type mismatch. So first you need to update: 
`swap(&ptr_x, &ptr_y);`

to 
`swap(ptr_x, ptr_y);`
The rest i would advise you to go through this link to understand how pointers are used to swap the values by call by reference method:
https://www.studymite.com/blog/swapping-values-using-pointer-in-c